# Jeditable & ASP, I can't see POST values on processing page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable, I'm working in localhost (don't know if it does matter) and I can't see any value sent to AJAX page.

JS code:

```
 $('.editable').editable('/mypage.asp?act=update-profile', {
             type      : 'textarea',
             cancel    : 'Cancel',
             submit    : 'OK',
             indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
             tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
         });
```

HTML

```
<p class="editable" id="testo_it">Some text here</p>
```

mypage.asp

```
        <%
    testo_it    = Request.form("testo_it")

response.write testo_it
    %>
```

variable "testo_it" is empty!

any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation:](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

> When submitting change following data will be POST:ed to server:
>
> id=elements_id&value=user_edited_content

So you need to get the value as:

```
Request.Form("value")
```